# my entity relationship database design cannot work -for location app

Tags: java, sql, database

I am building a location app which also allows messaging function. however, I am not sure of how can I design my EER Diagram. I currently have a user table, contacts table(for tracking and messaging purposes) as well as a message table(for users to interact with one another). However, I feel there is something missing in the tables and my current database design does not allow messaging. Can anyone help me with this? The attached is my database scheme diagram. Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kg5M.png)

Comment: can you elaborate this statement "my current database design does not allow messaging"

Comment: i'm not sure if my database design will allow messaging function, but i do not know how to make my database able to allow messaging on the app

Comment: always if you have to perform messaging like sending email, you do it as a separate job like Windows Service, Azure WebJobs etc